# Adding object to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can not figure out why my objects have the same values, I think I am creating a new object every time.

```
for (i = row; i <= y; i++) {    
    if (t !== 0 && $('#' + i + '' + col).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        console.clear(); //testing
        var obj = {
            rows: i,
            cols: col
        };
        vblack.push(obj);
        vred.length = 0;    

        //testing purposes only, printing contents of vblack array
        for (var j = 0; j < vblack.length; j++) {

            console.log("j " + j + " rows " + obj.rows + " col " + obj.cols);

        };

    } else if (t === 0 && $('#' + i + '' + col).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        var obj = {
            rows: i,
            cols: col
        };
        vred.push(obj);
        vblack.length = 0;    
    }
}
```

Prints this to the console log

```
j 0 rows 7 col 7
j 1 rows 7 col 7
j 2 rows 7 col 7
j 3 rows 7 col 7
```

What I'm expecting to print out is, 
rows 4 col 7
rows 5 col 7
rows 6 col 7
rows 7 col 7

I'm trying to log x and y coordinates of a table depending on background color, if a red one is between black ones I set the vblack array back to 0.

Comment: hell y u no format your code?

Comment: you are printing out obj, but I suspect you meant to print out vblack[j], no?

Comment: What do you expect to print out

Comment: you are creating a new obj for each i, not for each j

Comment: Your print loop is inside the loop that adds the elements to the array, so it just shows the current object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `console.log` loop outside the assignment loop.

```
for (i = row; i <= y; i++) {    
    if (t !== 0 && $('#' + i + '' + col).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        var obj = {
            rows: i,
            cols: col
        };
        vblack.push(obj);
        vred.length = 0;    

    } else if (t === 0 && $('#' + i + '' + col).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
        var obj = {
            rows: i,
            cols: col
        };
        vred.push(obj);
        vblack.length = 0;    
    }
}

//testing purposes only
console.clear();
console.log("Black:");
for (var j = 0; j < vblack.length; j++) {
    console.log("j " + j + " rows " + vblack[j].rows + " col " + vblack[j].cols);
};
console.log("Red:");
for (var j = 0; j < vred.length; j++) {
    console.log("j " + j + " rows " + vred[j].rows + " col " + vred[j].cols);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to watch with Javascript Arrays, the index is not always sequential.  Instead of

```
for( var j = 0....
```

prefer

```
for (j in vblack)
```

It's nice to think that vblack would have elements 0-n always, but it is not always the case and .length will report n+1.